# Replace 'collection_select, :multiple => true' with multiple 'check_box' options in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do you replace a `collection_select` (with `:multiple => true`) with a list of `check_box` options, such that there is a `check_box` option for each object in the collection?

Is there an **elegant** way to implement this using form builders (i.e. without using `*_tag` helpers)?  I'd like to lean on ActiveRecord's built in functionality as much as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in "elegant" way to do this.

This railscast should get you going, though:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes
- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes (text versionn)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (example using HAML).

```
%fieldset
  Colors I like
  - %w[red blue].each do |color|
    = f.label color 
    = f.check_box :colors_liked, {multiple: true}, color, nil
```

The `nil` option at the end prevents Rails from building a hidden checkbox by the same name with a 0 value, which you definitely don't want if you're going for multiple selection.

This produces:

```
<label for="colors_liked_red">Red</label>
<input id="my_form_colors_liked_red" \
  name="my_form[colors_liked][]" type="checkbox" value="red">

<label for="colors_liked_blue">Blue</label>
<input id="my_form_colors_liked_blue" \
  name="my_form[colors_liked][]" type="checkbox" value="blue">
```

When the form is submitted, the parameters will contain an array of the values of the checked options.