# How do I present a HABTM relationship with a drop-down menu in a form and have an option to add more?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a habtm relationship between two models. Researchers and Universities. In my Researcher form how can I have the ability to select one University from list of existing Universities, and then click an add button to add a second (or more) university if that Researcher has a relationship with more than one?

Listing the item once is simple:

```
<%= collection_select(:researcher, :university_ids, University.order("name"), :id, :name %>
```

But it's not clear to me how to add more than one of these drop-downs to my form.

For example, by default the form has one drop-down listing the universities, and you can select one item from that list. But, if you'd like to add a second university, you can click "Add another" and that adds an identical drop-down list to the form with the same list of universities. From this list you can select another university that will also be associated with this researcher.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to enable multiple selections in your select box. Here's an article on [how to enable multiple selections on a collection select](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/ruby/threads/74804/collection_select-with-selected-option).

But like this [answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300384/replace-collection-select-multiple-true-with-multiple-check-box-options), this isn't the best UI. Simpleform handles this with checkboxes out of the box.

And this railscast is quite old (#17!!), but looks to still work: http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Comment: Agreed that check boxes or a multi-select on a single collection select are not great UI experiences. I'm thinking that the UI that makes the most sense is where you can add a new drop-down selector for each additional item. There will likely be more than 50 items in the list of Universities, so a listing of all of them with a checkbox to select them isn't ideal.

Comment: @Bob. Sorry, not following you on the multiple select boxes -- if I can help you further, let me know!

Comment: Thanks @Jesse. I added additional details above. Perhaps this is more of a JavaScript/jQuery question than a Rails one. (??)

Comment: Check out http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 on a good way to add more models to your form using query